# Projectile motion as realistic as possible (at least computationally)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag, models, coriolis-effect

I want to know how would one set up the equation of motion of a projectile, that takes the most effects into account as possible (such as air resistance, lift, the projectile's extension, Earth's rotation, variable gravity, etc.), while still being computationally feasible, and solvable using programs such as Matlab or Mathematica, and being as realistic as possible, unlike the equations given in all introductory physics courses, $x(t)=v_0 \cos(\theta)t, y(t)=v_0\sin(\theta)t-\frac{1}{2}gt^2$, which are not accurate for many real life projectiles, since they describe a point particle under a constant force of gravity in a vacuum. I want to have an "anti-ideal" equation for a projectile, if you let me call it like that.

I guess that the equations of motion would be rather messy, and obviously they would be nonlinear.

Comment: Since you're talking in vague terms -- "most", "as ... as possible", etc., there is no one answer.  In the end, _you_ have to decide what's feasible or not (i.e., a 20 year old laptop is infeasible for some, a 20,000 square foot server farm is feasible for others).  Then _you_ have to decide what's realistic enough, neat enough, etc.

Comment: In general terms, yes, any aerodynamic solution is nonlinear.  There's easier ones (you could assume subsonic flow, a constant drag coefficient, and standard atmosphere), or complicated ones (a complete millisecond-by-millisecond CFD solution) -- but which one you choose gets back to "feasible enough" and "realistic enough" and the balance between the two.

Comment: This kind of thing is not really what physics is about. Physicists excel at understanding what matters and what doesn’t, and when, and why.

Comment: Often times we break these problems down into "regimes."  For instance, I needn't concern myself with the Eötvös effect if I am shooting a bullet 100 yards, and I darn well better consider it if I am shooting a railroad cannon projectile 100 km.  There are different combinations of ranges, velocities, and inclination of fire where Magnus, Coriolis, spin drift, or even local gravity do, or don't matter.  You have to decide what the boundary of your quest is.  I am serious about long range rifle ballistics, but not orbital mechanics, and so I am able to contain my curiosity to that envelope.

Answer (score 1):

Is numerical integration an option? If so, you can simply start by modelling the projectile as a point mass, and define its initial conditions(mass, position, velocity), and the Net Force that acts on it at every instance.

If you are using a program like Matlab or even a programming language, you can simply define this force in its own function, say GetNetF(projectile, extra_fields, time).

The main loop of the simulator "won't care" what this function does, it will just use it to calculate the instantaneous acceleration  of the projectile, so you can make it as simple(constant gravity) or as complex(drag, wind, lift, variable gravity, magnetism, pseudo-random perturbations, whatever) as you like. The force can depend on the state of the projectile, and also any other external forces or fields you want to add. If you want to represent the atmosphere as several fields for density, pressure, heat, wind, moisture, etc that change due to the motion of the projectile(or other "global" factors) and also act upon the projectile itself through this Force, then you can do so(in that case most of the computation will be spent simulating the fields themselves, not the projectile).

Now if you want the projectile to have actual volume, you have to also define its shape and angular momentum/torque, but the principle is the same.

This seems to be doing what you're talking about, and also comes with source code.

https://jfuchs.hotell.kau.se/kurs/amek/prst/06_simu.pdf

Of course, like other posters mentioned, it all depends on what you want to do. If the function for the net force becomes non-linear, the "time-step" you will use for the integration/simulation *will* affect the accuracy of the model. If this is, for instance, for a Worms-like videogame, then "good enough" is a pretty low bar, because in those cases you mostly care about the appearance of "physically realistic" than actually being so. Your biggest problem in those cases will probably be the simulation running unpredictably differently in different machines and setups, so better use a fixed timestep. If, OTOH, it is for a flight simulator that is used by the military, then obviously you need a much more accurate model and computational power, and you will have to read on methods of optimization and mitigating the loss of accuracy.

As an aside, PCs these days *are* pretty powerful, and if you manage to use GPU as a general-purpose processor(which is also straightforward enough today) then even more. But again, it all depends on what your goal is here.